# Ladder operators in coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, coherence

When trying to find the expectation values of $x^2$ and $p^2$ for a coherent (time-dependant) state, I've run into some problems with the ladder operators.
Since it's a coherent state, $a_- \Psi(x,t) = \alpha (t) \Psi(x,t)$, where $\alpha(t)=\alpha_0(\cos(\omega t)-i \sin(\omega t))$.

More specifically if I have $I \equiv \int \Psi(x,t)^* (a_-a_+) \Psi(x,t) dx $,  how do I manipulate this to something I can work on? 
I know that $ a_-a_+\psi_n = (n+1)\psi_n$, but does that mean, that $I = (n+1)\int \Psi(x,t)^*\Psi(x,t) dx $? And in that case with a normalized $\Psi$, will the result just become 1? In other words: How should I interpret the $n$ when looking at $\Psi(x,t)$ instead of just one single state at the time?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please take some time to read the [site tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour). There's a very nice system on this site for voting up/down and other things that I hope you'll become familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of confusing notation.
You've written $(a_- a_+)\psi_n = (n+1)\psi_n$ where here you're thinking of $n$ as a number.
That only works because $\psi_n$ is an eigenstate of the number *operator*.
To get this right, remember that
$$ a_- a_+ = a_+ a_- + 1 \, .$$
We can use the shorter notation $n = a_+ a_-$ but only if we remember that here "$n$" is an operator.

Let's avoid this confusing notation and see what we can do with your problem.
First, more notation.
Let's write the coherent state with eigenvalue $\alpha$ as $|\alpha \rangle$, as this makes it a lot easier to remember that the state is a coherent state with that eigenvalue!

Second, let's use vector notation instead of integrals.
The integral $I$ you defined is just
$$I = \langle \alpha| a_- a_+ | \alpha \rangle \, . $$

Now we just work it out
\begin{align}
\langle a_- a_+ \rangle
&= \langle \alpha | 1 + a_+ a_- | \alpha \rangle \tag{1} \\
&= 1 + \langle \alpha |a_+ a_-|\alpha \rangle \tag{2} \\
&= 1 + |a|^2 \tag{3} \\
\end{align}
where in going from (2) to (3) we used the facts that
$$ a_- |\alpha \rangle = \alpha |\alpha \rangle \quad \text{and} \quad \langle \alpha | a_+ = a^* \langle \alpha | \, .$$

I'm not quite sure why you wanted to compute that particular expectation value.
If you're interested in $\langle x^2 \rangle$, we expand it out and again and just work through it.
You should get
$$ \langle x^2 \rangle = x_0^2 \left( \alpha^2 + (\alpha^*)^2 + 2|\alpha|^2 + 1 \right) $$
where $x_0$ depends on the relation between $x$ and the raising/lowering operators.
If the Hamiltonian is
$$H = \frac{a}{2} x^2 + \frac{b}{2} p^2$$
then $x_0^2 = (\hbar/2) \sqrt{b/a}$.

Often, you care more about $\langle x^2 \rangle - \langle x \rangle^2$, and at this point I'm sure you can work that out too.